# Python C API: WindowsError after creating some number of PyObjects

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes, python-c-api

I've been having an issue getting the Python C API to not give me errors.

**Background:** I've been using `ctypes` to run native code (C++) for a while, but until now I had never actually done anything specific with the Python C API. I had mostly just been passing in structs from Python and filling them from C++. The way I was using structs was becoming cumbersome, so I decided I would try creating Python objects directly in C++ and just pass them back to my Python script.

**Code:**
I have a DLL (`Foo.dll`) with only one function:

```
#define N 223
__declspec(dllexport) void Bar(void)
{
    std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        auto list = PyList_New(0);
        std::cout << "Created: " << i << std::endl;
        //Py_DECREF(list);
    }
}
```

And then I have the Python script I'm running:

```
import ctypes as C
dll = r"C:\path\to\dll\Foo.dll"
Foo = C.CDLL(dll)
# lists = [[] for _ in range(0)]
Foo.Bar()
print "Done."
```

**What happens:** If I define `N` in the above DLL to be `222` or below, the code works fine (except for the memory leak, but that isn't the problem).

If I uncomment the `//Py_DECREF(list)` line, the code works fine.

However, with the above code, I get this:

```
Bar
Created: 0
Created: 1
Created: 2
...(omitted for your sake)
Created: 219
Created: 220
Created: 221
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path_to_script\script.py", line 9, in <module>
    Foo.Bar()
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000028
```

In fact, I get this same result with dictionaries, lists, tuples and so on. I get the same result if I create a list and then append empty sublists to that list.

What's weirder, every list that I make from within the actual Python script will decrease the number of lists the DLL can make before getting this windows error.

Weirder still, if I make more than 222 lists in my python script, then the DLL won't encounter this error until it's created something like 720 *more* lists.

**Other details: **

- Windows 10
- Using the Anaconda2 32-bit Python 2.7 distribution
- (Using `Python.h` and `python27.lib` from that distribution
- python.exe --version: `2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (32-bit)`
- Creating DLL with Visual Studio 2017

As long as I don't create many `PyObject`s from my C++ code, everything seems to work fine. I can pass `PyObject`s to and from the Python code and it works fine.. until I've created "too many" of the objects from within my C++ code.

**What is going on?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation for CDLL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL):

> The Python global interpreter lock is released before calling any function exported by these libraries, and reacquired afterwards.

This makes it *unsafe* to use Python C API code. Exactly how it fails is unpredictable, as you are finding. I'd guess it has to do with if the allocation triggers a run of the garbage collector, but I don't think it's worth spending too much time trying to work out the exact cause.

There's (at least) two solutions to chose from:

1. Use `ctypes.PyDLL` (which the documentation notes is like `CDLL` except that it does not release the GIL)
2. Reacquire the GIL within your C++ code - an easy way to do this is:

   ```
   auto state = PyGILState_Ensure();
   // C++ code requiring GIL - probably your entire loop
   PyGILState_Release(state);
   ```

Comment: I've confirmed that both solutions appear to solve the problem. How dare they expect me to actually _read the documentation_!?  Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I started working from the idea that "mystery errors when you're doing something simple with the Python C API is usually due to the GIL or not initialising Python" then just searched the ctypes documentation for GIL. I didn't actual read the documentation in detail either.